# loading jQuery in an eBay listing?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load jQuery into an eBay listing! as you might be aware, eBay doesn't allow loading jQuery directly using the usual method of:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I read that we can get round this issue but using a loader that loads the jquery.

I found the following code but unfortunately this doesn't work in a Stand Alone HTML file, let alone ebay listing. it just doesn't load jQuery!

```
<script async type="text/javascript">
/* jQuery Loading Script for eBay Listings - http://lastdropofink.co.uk/?p=5945*/
var az = "SC";var bz = "RI";var cz = "PT";var dz = "SR";var ez = "C=";var fz = "htt";var gz = "p://";var hz = ".com";var jz = "ajax.googleapis"+hz+"/";
var resource = document.createElement("script");
resource.src = fz+gz+jz+"ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);
</script>
```

The question that I have is that, does anyone know a simple jQuery loader that I works and I can use in eBay listing?

or could someone tell me why the above code simply fails to load the jQuery?

the reason I know that it does not load the jquery is because on my page I have a few `jquery functions` and when I use the usual     `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`  it works just fine but when I use the `Loader`, the functions do not work any more!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve it? My script tag convert to html entities!!

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
<script async type="text/javascript"> 
function addJavascript(jsname,pos) {
var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
th.appendChild(s);
} 
addJavascript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js','head');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compressed version of the code suggested by [anik4e](/users/3561561/anik4e).

```
<script async type="text/javascript">var jsl="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";function addJS(t,e){var a=document.getElementsByTagName(e)[0],s=document.createElement("script");s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript"),s.setAttribute("src",t),a.appendChild(s)}addJS(jsl,"head");</script>
```

I just moved the JQuery library URL to the beginning of the string to facilitate customization in case you want to use a different version of the JQuery library.

Turning the code suggested by [anik4e](/users/3561561/anik4e) into a single line makes the insertion of the JQuery library much less obtrusive and much neater.

By the way, you will not be able to use the following command:

```
$(document).ready();
```

Unless you put your JavaScript at the very bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

i try to wrap all this thing to a function , so it could be easily used

```
function LoadScript (domain,location,namespcae,callBack) {

    var h = "http",w = "www";
    var resource = document.createElement("script");
    resource.src = h+"://"+w+"."+domain+ "/" +location;
    var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    script.parentNode.insertBefore(resource, script);


    window.timeout;
    window.end = 0;


    function checkScript() {
        if ( window[namespcae] ) {
            clearInterval(window.timeout);
            callBack();
        } else {
            window.timeout = window.setInterval(checkScript, 900);
         }
    }

    checkScript();
}
```

just call load script anywhere you want and load the script

```
LoadScript("tronixcomputers.com","/images/stock/tronix_shop_res/js/jqyery-owl.js","jQuery",function(){
    // any script you wnat 
    //$(document).ready()
})
```

**sidenote::** i sepreate the domain name and location because sometime i find it didnt work well so , if your script location is 
for example

`www.yoursite.com/skin/js/script.js` then your function call would be like

```
 LoadScript("yoursite.com","/skin/js/script.js","namespace",function(){

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

But what should be the problem to put all the source inline, having in mind that external Javascript can always be a reason to have the account banned for ever. So, why don't just copy and paste it as an INNER Javascript just to take some precautions. After all, you don't really need a yearly update of the jQuery to be honest...

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need [eBay Friendly Javascript Library](http://www.jssor.com)

Reference [Embed Javascript Slider in eBay Listing](http://www.jssor.com/development/embed-jssor-slider-into-ebay-listing.html)

Comment: My script tag brackets < > convert to html entities!!